# Máscara para apenas deixar inserir letras e letras com acentos

Tags: javascript, html

Queria uma máscara para uma caixa de texto em que o utilizador apenas consegue inserir letras e letras com acentos.

O código que consegui encontrar apenas deixa inserir letras sem acentos.

```
function lettersOnly(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
    var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
    if (charCode == 32)
        return true;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

A variável `evt` é a letra premida ou seja, na textbox estou a usar a propriedade `onkeypress="return lettersOnly(event)"`.

Comment: Amigo, você pode utilizar REGEX, segue o link para ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar este plugin imaskjs

```js
var regExpMask = IMask(
  document.getElementById('regexp-mask'),
  {
    mask: /^[a-zöüóőúéáàűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁÀŰÍçÇ]{0,100}$/
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="regexp-mask">
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta um simples `.test` com uma regex e um flag `i` (de *case insensitive*, tanto faz maiúsculas ou minúsculas):

```js
function lettersOnly(evt) {
   if(!/[a-záéíóúàèìòùãõâêîôûäëïöüç]/i.test(evt.key)) return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onKeyPress="return lettersOnly(event)">
```

A regex irá validar todas as letras de `a` a `z` (maiúsculas ou minúsculas) e todas as letras acentuadas `áéíóúàèìòùãõâêîôûäëïöüç` (maiúsculas ou minúsculas).

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para atualizar as outras respostas, [segundo a MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event), atualmente o evento `keypress` está *deprecated* e seu uso não é mais recomendado:

> ***Deprecated**: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event#browser_compatibility) at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.*

Tanto que o W3C atualmente lista este evento na seção ["***Legacy** KeyboardEvent events*"](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#legacy-keyboardevent-events). Inclusive, lá menciona que ele foi substituído por `beforeinput` e `input`. Então uma versão mais atualizada ficaria assim:

```js
// qualquer caractere que não seja letra
const regexNaoLetras = /[^a-záéíóúàèìòùãõâêîôûäëïöüç]/ig;
function verify(e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(regexNaoLetras, '');
}

document.querySelector('#mask').addEventListener('input', verify);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="mask">
```

Além disso, o evento `input` também trata de casos que `keypress` não consegue lidar, como por exemplo se você fizer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> no campo. Ex: vamos supor que o valor atual do campo é "abc". Você copia (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) um número (como `123`) de outro lugar e cola (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) no campo. O evento `keypress` não consegue detectar isso e os números não são removidos (o valor do campo fica como "abc123"). Já o evento `input` detecta esta alteração e o seu respectivo *listener* é disparado.

Dentro do *listener* removemos os caracteres que não são letras (repare no `^` logo depois do `[`, isso faz com que a regex considere os caracteres que **não** estão na lista, ou seja, é qualquer coisa que não seja uma letra). A regex tem as [*flags*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) `i` (*case insensitive*, assim pega tanto letras maiúsculas quanto minúsculas) e `g` (*global*, que faz com que todas as ocorrências sejam substituídas).

Fiz desta forma, removendo todos os caracteres que não são letras, pois isto já cobre casos diferentes de uma digitação "normal", como por exemplo um <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> que pode adicionar vários caracteres de uma vez.